# asp.net web config appSettings in null in masterpage

Tags: asp.net, web-config, master-pages, configuration-files, appsettings

I have got an ASP.NET web application. In one of its folders there are several master pages and also a web.config file. The problem is that when I read appSettings in a master page page_load all of the appSettings in that web.config file are null. Instead it contains the website 's main web.config file appsettings when I try to read allkeys in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the folder for the web.config you want as follows:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration c = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/folder");
```

Reading: [System.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx)